# Understanding Cross-Domain issue in Iframes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

This question might seem silly but I need to understand this for clarity.

According to my understanding, cross-domain problem is when the domain of the webpage which contains the IFRAME is different from the domain of the web-page opened in IFRAME.

Going by that logic, nothing should open in IFRAME ever.

When I embed a web-page "bottom:10700" in the IFRAME of my web-page "top:9700", it gives error.I am not able to see the contents in IFRAME. Error is `Access denied in accessing property 'constructor'`

I am getting the error while accessing the contructor (_1.contructor)

```
isc.A.Function=function isc_isA_Function(_1){
  if(_1==null) return false;
  if(isc.Browser.isIE&&typeof _1==this.$a7) return true;
  var _2=_1.constructor;
  if(_2&&_2.$k!=null){
    if(_2.$k!=1)return false;
    if(_2===Function)return true
  }
```

This script is run when home page of bottom is opened in an iframe contained in top.

Is there any way, I can make this work. I mean can I set both the domains to be same. I don't have access to remote site's script.

Is resizing the frame after redering it once a cross-domain scenario. If not, then certainly remote site is trying to access the IFRAME element..How can I debug this??

Comment: It's not that you couldn't open a web page outside your domain. You just can't access it after you do.

Comment: In my case, my website url is "http://top:9700". This page contains an IFRAME which embeds url "http://botton:10700". I am not able to see the contents in iframe. Error is "Access denied in accessing property 'constructor'"...How come it is not working?

Comment: [Same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)  includes port and protocol

Comment: in my case, ports are different but still I should be able to see the web-page in IFRAME according to what Juhana said..

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a question which includes the HTML of the page.

Comment: Yes you should - if it is html and there is not a script trying to access the parent frame before it writes the content to the page. Please elaborate on what is in the bottom and top

Comment: These are not simple html pages..I am getting the error on this line while accessing the contructor  ",isc.A.Function=function isc_isA_Function(_1){if(_1==null)return false;if(isc.Browser.isIE&&typeof _1==this.$a7)return true;var _2=_1.constructor;if(_2&&_2.$k!=null){if(_2.$k!=1)return false;if(_2===Function)return true}"....This script is run when home page of bottom is opened in an iframe...

Comment: I have updated your question with relevant information from your comments. Please correct and add what is needed. Your initial question was incomplete and missed very relevant information such as port number

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cross-domain issues are about the communication between iframes. You can always embed any iframe but, if domains differ, iframes cannot interact with each other e.g. execute JS, modify DOM etc.

HTML5 provides a [`sandbox` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) that re-enables particular features of the cross-domain iframe interaction. Be careful, it can be dangerous.

Comment: If I resize a frame (through code) after showing it, is it considered as cross domain communication?

Comment: Nope. You resize a DOM element in a topmost window. This has nothing to do with any kind of communication.

Comment: I figured the issue..The issue was in the remote site's script. It was trying to align itself within the frame. To do that, it was accessing an element of frame's containing page...Thanks everyone for helping me

Answer (score 3):

It is normal behavior for a page xyz.com to load in an iframe hosted on abc.com. However, you cannot change anything or access its content via code from parent abc.com.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I understand it now. In my case, I am not trying to access any frame's content. So, perhaps it is remote script which is trying to access the containing page of my IFRAME. How can I debug, what is being accessed and fix it?