# Echo iframe inside input element for editing

Tags: php, html, iframe

Hello I would like to know how I can echo iframe code from database inside input for editing:

```
<input type="text" id="GoogleMaps" value="<?php echo $row['google_maps']; ?>" name="google_maps" >
```

Where the iframe code is:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d121090.52535268509!2d-69.94687995!3d18.4800842!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2sdo!4v1438714937162" width="1140" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Right now is showing some part of the code but without input. Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Read this: http://blog.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197653/understanding-cross-domain-issue-in-iframes

Comment: Make the `iframe` **`contenteditable=true`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because of quotes - PHP doesn't care where it echoes a string and your final code ends up being something like this:

```
... value="<iframe src="https: ...
          ^  and here  ^
```

You see what the problem is? Two double-quotes which are not a pair.

Make sure you escape all the inner quotes that are coming from PHP and then it will work as an input value. Though, in this specific case, it will work even if you replace all the double quotes in your PHP string into single quotes, but I'd still suggest proper escaping.

There are tons of tutorials about escaping, here are two I quickly googled:

- http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php7p7.html
- http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/phpTutorial/quotes.htm#o1Escaping_with_th_backslash