# Same Origin issue accessing iframe from jQuery in browser console

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to automate interactions with a website that I don't control.  Notably for this discussion, the page from the site contains several iframes.  For example, consider the source of the imaginary (but comparable) page https://www.chicken.com/a/b/hamburger.aspx to look something like:

```
<html>
    ... 
    <iframe id="iframe_a" src="meatloaf.aspx"></iframe>
    <iframe id="iframe_b" src="stuffing.aspx"></iframe>
    ...
</html>
```

Notably, the 'src' attributes of the iframes are relative, so they are to be loaded from the original domain (www.chicken.com/a/b/ in this case) and there doesn't seem to be any 'Same Origin' issues, since I can login to the site and interact with it just fine.  However, this all changes when I try to interact with the iframes using the Chrome dev console.  For instance, this is what happens when I try to get the contents of one of the iframes using jQuery:

```
$('#iframe_a').contents()

jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.chicken.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.(…)
```

My (wrong) intuition is that since the sources of these iframes is the same domain as is the original page, that javascript interactions in the console should be under the auspices of that original domain, and everything should be fine.  But clearly I'm not understanding the nuances of Same Origin.  Can someone enlighten me about how it works in this case?  And perhaps suggest a way to manipulate the contents of this iframe from a running browser?

Comment: Take a look to [Understanding Cross-Domain issue in Iframes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197653/understanding-cross-domain-issue-in-iframes)

Comment: it should work, you might have https redirect issues

Comment: @gaemaf, I looked at your link.  As far as I can tell it doesn't apply, since in this case the iframes are _not_ cross-domain.

Comment: @shanusmagnus Sorry for my misunderstanding, in any case I repeated your condition on my webserver and I do not get the jquery-1.11.3.min.js error. I used the same jQuery library and the last version on chrome. I can only assume the problem is in another part, like hidden redirection from theserver side or ... I do not know. Thanks for your patience. I tried also with ie11 and no problem.

Comment: @gaemaf thanks for the additional datapoint, that's really helpful.  I'll try to screw this down more and see if I can refine my question.

Comment: @dandavis any recs on getting more info about the interplay with https in this situation?

Comment: @shanusmagnus I am having the same problem on a possible work.......The error is the same: the problem is clear CORS.