# iFrame - Auto Height on content change within iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have the following code:-

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
</script>

<div class="resizable">
    <iframe src="http://yellow-taxi.co.uk/onlinebooking/index.php" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)"></iframe>
</div>
```

The Javascript goes it adjusting the height to what the initial height of the iFrame is, but the height of the iFrame increases as you go through the booking process. Is there a way to auto adjust the height of the iFrame based on the content that lays inside it as the content changes?

**Note:** The iFrame is displayed on the same domain as the iFrame src.

Comment: Do you have any javascript libraries (jQuery) available to use?

Comment: Yes `jquery-1.9.1.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  No Jquery needed, but you will have to call resizeIframe when the content changes.

```
function resizeIframe(obj) {
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight = document.getElementById(obj).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth = document.getElementById(obj).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(obj).height = (newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(obj).width = (newwidth) + "px";
}
```

Here's an example iFrame and the necessary attributes in it.  Be sure to call the above method with your iFrame name.

```
<iframe src="yourpage.htm" width="100%" height="300px" id="yourIframe" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onLoad="resizeIframe('yourIframe');"></iframe>
```

There's also a nice JQuery plugin that will accomplish the task, and supposedly works over domains as well:  https://github.com/house9/jquery-iframe-auto-height

Comment: this doesn't seem to be resizing anything, I'm calling it on every function

Comment: How are you calling it?  I'll update my answer with the iFrame I'm using in my example.

Comment: I believe there is a missing { on line 1 of your code in this answer.

Comment: There is indeed.  I updated the answer.  Thanks Menno!

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, you can't, unless your page is on the same domain as the iframe page.  You've run into a cross-domain limitation, and as a security measure set up by your browser, you won't be able to access JS, DOM elements, or properties within that iframe's content.

[SO Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197653/understanding-cross-domain-issue-in-iframes)

Comment: The iFrame is on the same domain.