# iframe auto height without scroll doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page that contains an iframe. I have tried to remove the scroll with the attribute scrolling=no and scroll='no' but without result.

So I want it to be able to adjust its height according to the contents inside it, without using scroll.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
  function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';

  }
</script>
<iframe    src="" frameborder="0"  onload="resizeIframe(this)"  scrolling="no > </iframe>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iFrame - Auto Height on content change within iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781928/iframe-auto-height-on-content-change-within-iframe)

Comment: no same problem

Comment: You won't be able to do this if your iframe points to another (sub) domain due to browsers' same-origin policy.

Comment: i want to Link external CSS file only for specific Div so is there another solution instead of iframe

Comment: Can you give us more information about the problem you are having, then? Just saying it doesn't work is not enough to go on.

Comment: the probleme is that the iframe get always a very small width and the  scroll is always shown  and i want to adjust its height  to the contents without the scroll

Answer (score 0):

I dont fully understand what you are trying to accomplish here and I presume the Iframe doesnt provide an API to handle this for you.

No scrolling:
Its a workaround but: fix this by wrapping the Iframe with a div, putting it on top of it with z-index. The cursor will not access the Iframe like this. Also want to be able to click it? Add an onclick function removing the diff or the css of the div.

Altering the height:
Just dont specify height and width and the IFrame will handle this for you?

About the code:
Im not familiar with the onload function but presuming it runs after the loading of the Iframe...

```
 obj.style.height
```

should be

```
 obj.height
```

Comment: same problem scroll is there too