# Iframe contentWindow on different domain

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain-policy

I'm working on custom scrolling for a page that will be hosted on domain B and opened in an iframe from a site hosted on domain A. I need to get frame's height and width like this:

```
clientHeight = parent.document.getElementById("mainForm").contentWindow.innerHeight || parent.document.getElementById("mainForm").offsetHeight;
```

This works when both pages are on the same domain but doesn't work when they're on different domains. I know I can use `postMessage` to request and get this information, I'm just not sure how to access frame size from the hosting page on domain A either. Things like `window.frames['abc'].contentWindow` are also blocked. Any ideas?

P.S.: I did search this topic and found many similar topics, none of them answers this specific questions.

Comment: Just to make sure I was clear enough. This: "clientHeight = parent.document.getElementById("mainForm").contentWindow.innerHeight || parent.document.getElementById("mainForm").offsetHeight;" doesn't work on domain B. This: "window.frames['mainForm'].contentWindow doesn't work on domain A. Looks like I can't access contentWindow from neither of the domains. Why is this the case and is there a workaround?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14197877/6813791

Comment: remove site B scripts

Answer (score 0):

> The “Same Origin” (same site) policy limits access of windows and
> frames to each other.
>
> The idea is that if a user has two pages open: one from
> john-smith.com, and another one is gmail.com, then they wouldn’t want
> a script from john-smith.com to read our mail from gmail.com. So, the
> purpose of the “Same Origin” policy is to protect users from
> information theft.

https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication

From the same article - a possible solution is to use the PostMessage API to communicate between the two pages:

https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication#postmessage

More info at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage