# running a html/script/css in an isolated space like iframe but without iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, javascript-security

I having some in house ad serving that serve html5 ads each ad contain its own css js and html.

i cant just put them in iframe because the website is based a lot of touch gesture and touch not working over iframe.

I can put `pointer-events: none;` over the iframe but then the ads won't be intractable.

so is there some special way of creating isolated chunk of code like iframe without iframes?

example:

```
<div class="website">
<h1> title</h1>

<isolate>
     every thing inside here will not be able to interact withevery thing outside isolate
    <script>
         $('h1') = will be empty because there is no h1 inside the isolated area
    </script>
</isolate>
```

*all the code the parent website and the ads sit on same website

Comment: Did you try inserting HTML through javascript?

Comment: I think my question was unclear :) I need a way to insert a html\js into the page and make sure it cant change any of the current html like iframe

Comment: simply put it on a <div>

Comment: @RexAdrivan nope.. if you let anyone insert js into your html they will be able to change your whole website

Comment: You can check this article about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197653/understanding-cross-domain-issue-in-iframes

Answer (score -2):

You could possibly create your own selector function which could extend jQuery selector.

Maybe something like this:

```js
function $_(ws, selector) {
  return $(ws).find(selector);
}

$(function(){
  result.innerHTML = $_(myIsolatedWorkspace, 'h1').text()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello world</h1>

<div id="myIsolatedWorkspace">
  <h1>Hello isolated world</h1>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

You could do something like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299846/obtain-a-reference-to-script-parent-element) answer to obtain a reference to script's parent tag.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello world</h1>

<div class="isolated">
  <h1>Hello isolated world</h1>
  <script>
    (function(){
      var scriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
      scriptTag = scriptTag[scriptTag.length - 1];
      var isolated = $(scriptTag).closest('.isolated');
      
      function _(selector) {
        return isolated.find(selector);
      }
      
      
      $(function(){
         result.innerHTML = _('h1').text()
      })
    })()
  </script>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```