# Jquery: Not running in Codepen project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codepen

Trying to run a project on Codepen and for some reason part of the JS is not running even though it did work in the individual pen.

Below the code:

HTML head

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/script.js"></script>
</head>
```

JS/Jquery

```
$( ".box-2,  .box-4").hover(
  function() {
    $('.row div').removeClass( "active" );
    $(this).addClass( "active" );
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass( "active" );
  }
);

window.setInterval(autohover, 3500);

  function autohover(){
    var numberg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 1;

    switch(numberg) {
      case 1:
        $('.row div').removeClass( "active" );
        $('#programming').addClass( "active" );
        break;
      case 2:
        $('.row div').removeClass( "active" );
        $('#design').addClass( "active" );
        break;
      case 3:
        $('.row div').removeClass( "active" );
        $('#healthfitness').addClass( "active" );
        break;
      case 4:
        $('.row div').removeClass( "active" );
        $('#astronomy').addClass( "active" );
        break;
      case 5:
        $('.row div').removeClass( "active" );
        $('#languages').addClass( "active" );
        break;
      case 6:
        $('.row div').removeClass( "active" );
        $('#photography').addClass( "active" );
        break;
      case 7:
        $('.row div').removeClass( "active" );
        $('#business').addClass( "active" );
        break;
      default:
      }
  }

$('.gotocoursesearch').on('click', function () {

            var scrto = $(".second").offset().top ;
                $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: scrto
                }, 1500);
        });

$('.questions button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).siblings('button').removeClass('activetwo');
  $(this).addClass('activetwo');
});
```

The only part that is running is the JS part (function autohover), so it seems like it's the Jquery that is not running.

Comment: I hope you have added the jquery in the javascript required classes dropdown

Comment: Please select jquery through dropdown

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean with through dropdown. Could you elaborate? I have added the jquery to the head as well as the script that it needs to run. Should I do more? @OmSao and Jeffin

Comment: @ValentijnvandenHout: There is an option to select which library you want in your code. You can select jquery from that dropdown.

Comment: @OmSao Ah, yes I know what you mean but that is only in the Codepen pens. Not in the project. In Project you can only add jquery via source code I believe. The external sources tab only allows link copy, no instant integration.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. In some way. More symptom kill than actually solving the source problem.

Somehow the Jquery did not load. I put the script code straight into the HTML code which made it work (browser Jquery load works).

However, I still don't know why the external script did not load properly.

Thanks for the answers/comments though!

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you load jQuery from a different domain and try to run it in an iFrame (your codepen live preview is actually loaded within an iframe) and loading external scripts within an iFrame violates a couple of security measures.
[Understanding Cross-Domain issue in Iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197653/understanding-cross-domain-issue-in-iframes)