# How to add custom CSS in iframe tag for Web view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my site to look different in app. How can I apply custom CSS to web view?

```
<iframe  src="https://url.com" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
  Your browser doesn't support iframes
</iframe>
```

Comment: ? Web view ? You want custom styles when the site is inside the frame? Than let the iframe requests `url.com?framed=true` for example, than set the cookie if necessary and serve additional css - simple as that.

Comment: Firstly- I need to ask, is the iframe of the same origin? You cannot modify iframes of another origin. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197653/understanding-cross-domain-issue-in-iframes